# InnoDB Memcached Plugin in earlier version of MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, innodb, libmemcache

Can we use [InnoDB Memcached Plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached-setup.html)  in an earlier version of MySQL 5.6, such as 5.1 or 5.5? I searched on the web but could not find anything about this.

I tried to do this, as follows. I downloaded `MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el7.x86_64.rpm` and then run the following command to extract it:

```
rpm2cpio MySQL-server-5.6.22-1.el7.x86_64.rpm  | cpio -idmv
```

and then copied `libmemcached.so` from `~/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin` to `/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin`,and then from these instructions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached-installing.html) ran the following command:

```
 mysql> install plugin daemon_memcached soname "libmemcached.so";
```

but I got the following error:

> Can't open shared library 'libmemcached.so' (errno:8, API version for DAEMON plugin   daemon_memcached not supported by this version of the server

My current version of MySQL is:

```
 mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.37-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: Still does not understand why i got -1 vote on my question after updating my question with detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my distribution from MariaDB to MySQL,and also test "InnoDB Memcached Plugin" in MySQL 5.1 and 5.5 but this plugin does not work.